# Replacing Placeholder within html?

Tags: javascript, dom

Im creating a todo app and im having trouble with replacing the placeholder with actual data within the html im inserting

CODE:

```
// Selecting elements
const clear = document.querySelector(".clear");
const dateElement = document.getElementById("date");
const list = document.getElementById("list");
const input = document.getElementById("input");

// Classes names
const CHECK = "fa-check-circle";
const UNCHECK = "fa-circle-thin";
const LINE_THROUGH = "LineThrough";

// Show todays date
const options = {weekday : "long", month:"short", day:"numeric"};
const today = new Date();
dateElement.innerHTML = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

function addToDo(toDo) {
    const item = '<li class="item"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin co" job="complete" id ="0"> </i><p class="text">${toDo}</p><i class = "fa fa-trash-o de" job="delete" id="0"></i></li>';

    const position = "beforeend";
    list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, item);


}

addToDo("Drink Coffee");
```

On the html part im trying to replace the ${toDo} with actual data. At the bottom i call the addToDo function with 'Drink coffee' as the data but all thats displayed is literally ${toDO} not Drink Coffee
Im not quite sure where im going wrong
Also sorry for the html formatting im not sure how to get it on multiple lines without error

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use back ticks ` instead of single/double quotes to have string interpolation

```
const item = `<li class="item"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin co" job="complete" id ="0"> </i><p class="text">${toDo}</p><i class = "fa fa-trash-o de" job="delete" id="0"></i></li>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently using a string literal:

```
const item = '<li class="item"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin co" job="complete" id ="0"> </i><p class="text">${toDo}</p><i class = "fa fa-trash-o de" job="delete" id="0"></i></li>';
```

Which doesn't replace variables with their values.  It sounds like you're looking for a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which uses back-ticks instead of single-quotes:

```
const item = `<li class="item"><i class="fa fa-circle-thin co" job="complete" id ="0"> </i><p class="text">${toDo}</p><i class = "fa fa-trash-o de" job="delete" id="0"></i></li>`;
```